# How to execute this in query Android Studio?

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

How can i execute query to get this result?

I want to `select * from TABLE_NAME` all Data that has different `TAKEN_DATE_TIME` on each `MED_ID`

```
return db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] { MED_ID,HIS_ID,TAKEN_DATE_TIME,SCHEDULED_DATE_TIME,TAKEN,MED_NAME },
TAKEN_DATE_TIME, null, MED_ID, null, HIS_ID+" DESC" , null);
```

This is the data in the database.
[image: This was the data in database]

Comment: Just look for Room in android Jetpack. Room makes it way easier than using DB in android. Search for Room on official website

Answer (score 0):

According to ***I want to select `*` from TABLE_NAME all Data that has different TAKEN_DATE_TIME on each MED_ID***

You would appear to want to run the query :-

```
SELECT * FROM hislist GROUP BY taken_datetime,med_id ORDER BY med_id;
```

Using the [SQLiteDatabase **query**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method you could use :-

```
return db.query(
    TABLE_NAME, /* FROM clause less FROM */
    null, /* all columns */
    null, /* selection i.e. WHERE clause less WHERE */
    null, /* bind  parameters */
    TAKEN_DATE_TIME + "," + MED_ID, /* GROUP BY clause less GROUP BY */
    null, /* HAVING clause less HAVING */
    null /* ORDER BY clause less ORDER BY */
);
```

- This creates groups of rows by MED_ID and then TAKEN_DATE_TIME thus a single group will be created for each different TAKEN_DATE_TIME within each MED_ID.

e.g. based upon a subset of your data (which incidentally has the same TAKEN_DATE_TIME within the MED_ID) the above results in :-

[image]

However if changing some of the TAKEN_DATE_TIME values for MED_ID **1** to be :-

[image]

The the result is that there will be 3 groups of different TAKEN_DATE_TIME's for MED_ID **1**, as per :-

[image]

Comment: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
for example: 
MED_A -  ID:1, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 3:37 AM
                ID:1, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 3:37 AM
                ID:1, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 4:37 AM
                ID:1, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 4:37 AM
                ID:1, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 5:37 AM

Comment: MED_B - ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 3:37 AM
                ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 3:37 AM
                ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 4:37 AM
                ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 4:37 AM
                ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 5:37 AM
                ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 5:37 AM

Comment: ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 6:37 AM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
i want the output to become like this:
MED_A -  ID:1, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 3:37 AM
                ID:1, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 4:37 AM
                ID:1, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 5:37 AM

Comment: MED_B - ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 3:37 AM
                ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 4:37 AM
                ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 5:37 AM
                ID:2, TAKEN_DATE_TIME: 11/10/2019 6:37 AM